# Net::HTTP does not automatically unzip gzipped response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gzip, net-http

According to the Compression section of the documentation of [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), it should automatically uncompress compressed responses. However, when I tried with a number of JSON requests with different servers, I am not getting automatic decompression.

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI("http://yourhost.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
res = http.get(uri.request_uri)
```

Comment: What type of compression is being returned? [Net::HTTP doesn't automatically handle everything](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-get).

Comment: The content returned is gzipped content.

Comment: You can test hitting http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/69655841&width=150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was being caused by `right_http_connection` gem which is in my bundle. The following gives proper decoded response in IRB.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
uri = URI("http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/69655841&width=150")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
res = http.get(uri.request_uri)
res.body
```

However, requiring `right_http_connection` starts giving a gzipped response.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'right_http_connection'
uri = URI("http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/69655841&width=150")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
res = http.get(uri.request_uri)
res.body
```

This is a known issue and its fix has already been [merged](https://github.com/rightscale/right_http_connection/pull/20) but a newer gem version containing the fix has not been released.